# How should I store an object which belongs to multiple other objects in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database, nosql

I have a project I've been working on recently using MongoDB. Basically, the core element of my website is "projects". Each project will contain a nested "strings" object, which will contain a large amount of strings... So, each project is quite massive and can approach a megabyte or more. As such, I want to have the projects in their own collection.

The problem I'm having is that I'm not for sure how to assign users to a project. Should a user contain a list of the projects they're enrolled in, or should the project contain a list of users? When should I choose one or the other? And is there a better way? (I haven't touched MongoDB in quite a while, so I'm a bit rusty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot immediately think of any serious stopping differences between the two. I suppose maintaining it user side might be easier for:

- User unsubscribing from projects since you just modify that user row which will likely have only that atomic lock on it anyway, unlike the project row which multiple users could be trying to unsubscribe from at the same time. So doing it user side might make better updates and concurrency in general.
- The previous point can apply to users subscribing to projects as well.
- User deletions, you just delete the user row...simple

So considering these immediate things that come to mind I would probably choose to embed projects within the user.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design. The guideline that would apply in your case is

> Generally, for "contains" relationships between entities, embedding should be be chosen. Use linking when not using linking would result in duplication of data.

If a user can be enrolled in multiple projects, and a project can enroll multiple users, it seems best to have separate collections for Projects and Users.